# Using jQuery viewer pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I need to use a Jquery script for using a viewer of pdf. But I don't know very well jQuery and I don't know how to use this script. What code I use for use this viewer pdf? 
I found this code but I don't see anything:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('a.media').media({width:500, height:400});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://github.com/malsup/media/raw/master/jquery.media.js?v0.92"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.metadata.js"></script> 

<a class="media" href="guice.pdf">PDF File</a> 
<a class="media {type: 'html'}" href="../">HTML File</a> 

</body>
</html>
```

What do I change in this code? Or WHat code do I write for using the jquery script for pdf viewer? Help me please

Answer (score 0):

To display pdf from other servers, you may embed google pdf viewer in your page.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```